# Error in SSIS package when executing using DTEXEC

Tags: sql, ssis

My SSIS packages are running smoothly when using both Visual Studio 2015 and DTEXEC in CMD. But there are some packages that are getting error when running using DTEXEC **ONLY** but not when running using VS2015.

Please see below error:

> To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Standard Edition of Integration Services or higher

[SSIS package error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ8xt.png)

I'm wondering why it only occurs in some packages only.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when asking questions here. Text in ALL CAPS is harder to read and understand, it's rude, and it won't get you help any faster if you SHOUT FOR ATTENTION. If someone can help you, they will do so without any SHOUTING. Thanks. And the answer would be *because some things require support that is provided in Integration Services and others don't*.

Answer (score 0):

Issue here is SQL Server Integration Services is not running  on the server.  There are some component in the package required the Services up and running .